# Method for high quality output in XNA 4.0

Tags: 3d, xna, xna-4.0, multisampling

I'm using this example project's XNA 4.0 form control in an application I'm writing:
http://creators.xna.com/en-US/sample/winforms_series1

It's working great and I've done quite a bit with visuals and animation. The main issue I'm scratching my head at is the 3d model and primitive 3D shapes (cylinders with a tessellation of 30) I render have very jagged edges to them as if they are low resolution.

I tried to figure out how to enable multisampling, but all of the examples I can find online don't seem to apply to this novel way of using XNA in the custom form control.

Inside the GraphicsDeviceService() constructor there is a PresentationParameters object created, but the only property available is parameters.MultiSampleCount of type integer. I tried setting that with no effect.

**I also attempted making the back-buffer twice as large as the control's size (GraphicsDeviceService.cs):**

```
    GraphicsDeviceService(IntPtr windowHandle, int width, int height)
    {
        parameters.BackBufferWidth = width * 2;
        parameters.BackBufferHeight = height * 2;
        ...
    }
```

**Then I changed this function (GraphicsDeviceControl.cs):**

```
    void EndDraw()
    {
        Rectangle sourceRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, ClientSize.Width * 2, ClientSize.Height * 2);
        Rectangle destinationRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height);
        GraphicsDevice.Present(sourceRectangle, destinationRectangle, this.Handle);
    }
```

But that didn't work properly. My objects rendered to the screen were relegated to 1/4th of the window and clipped. It did look slightly less jagged though...

So at this point I'm not sure what I can do to get high quality graphics using this method (XNA control in a window). I'm pretty new to XNA in general, so any suggestions would be most helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I downloaded that code sample to see where the PresentationParameters were being set up. These are what you need to modify.

It's in the GraphicsDeviceService class.

In the constructor of this class, it is setting up an object called "parameters", a PresentationParamters object. Add this line after the new and before passing the parameters to the graphicsDevice:

```
parameters.MultiSampleCount = 10;
```

That value I picked arbitrarily. It provides a healthy antialiasing. Read more about antialiasing if you need to understand what this number exactly is. It's the number of passes through the antialias filter. So you may want to lower it for better performance, or raise it for more antialiasing.

Comment: I'm sorry for not reading your answer completely, seems you already tried MultiSampleCount. It also seems like you may not have tried many different values. Try it with higher values; for me, I can definitely see the jagged edges when it's 1-2 and when I increase it to 10, the edges are very smooth. I have tested this with the default models that come with the code sample, like Cylinder, SpaceShip, etc.

Comment: Also I meant question! God I'm tired, sorry.

Comment: I appreciate your help Scott.  It doesn't seem to be having an effect in my case.  Maybe it's the laptop I'm using that's incapable?  (has Intel integrated graphics).  If it is completely hardware dependent, I'll have to look for another method.

Comment: What hardware model is it? Multisampling is supported in both Reach and HiDef graphics profiles, but your hardware has the final say on what features are enabled.

Comment: From this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphicsdevicemanager.prefermultisampling.aspx  it appears multisampling is ignored if hardware does not support it.

Comment: Well at least I know now that multisampling should work with that property if the hardware supports it...  I think I'm going to try a few other ideas though.

Comment: There are ways to accomplish it using shaders, check out this thread for ideas: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/469110-shader-based-anti-aliasing/

Answer (score 2):

There are a few properties of the GraphicsDeviceManager that you can set, make sure they are all done.

```
graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(<A reference to your game class>)
{
  PreferMultiSampling = true,
};

graphics.PreparingDeviceSettings += (s, e) =>
{
  e.GraphicsDeviceInformation.PresentationParameters.MultiSampleCount = 16;
};
```

Comment: The game class isn't available with the windows forms method.

Answer (score 0):

I had this EXACT problem. If you are using the XNA graphicsdevicecontrol object in a windows form, simply setting multisample count won't work. You have to modify the GraphicsDeviceService.cs in the initialization portion.

Look for this initialization so you can define the multisample count when you create your graphics device and not after the fact.

> GraphicsDeviceService(IntPtr windowHandle, int width, int height)
>
> {
>               parameters = new PresentationParameters();
>
> ```
>         parameters.BackBufferWidth = Math.Max(width, 1);
>         parameters.BackBufferHeight = Math.Max(height, 1);
>         parameters.BackBufferFormat = SurfaceFormat.Color;
>         parameters.DepthStencilFormat = DepthFormat.Depth24;
>         parameters.DeviceWindowHandle = windowHandle;
>         parameters.PresentationInterval = PresentInterval.Immediate;
>         parameters.IsFullScreen = false;
>         parameters.MultiSampleCount = 10; //  <--- RIGHT HERE
>
>         graphicsDevice = new GraphicsDevice(GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter,
>                                             GraphicsProfile.Reach,
>                                             parameters);
>     }
> ```

Anywhere else and the graphics device will ignore your changes