# Jagged edges, and weird shadowing

Tags: c#, xna

I am using XNA embedded in WinForms, dowloaded from Microsoft website. And have noticed that when models are drawn, everything looks ok, but as soon as I rotate my camera, edges on model start to look jagged. Here are two pictures of what I am talking about:

[image]

[image]

This is more visible as closer the camera is to the target. I am using this to draw each mesh:

```
foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
{
    foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
    {
        effect.View = cam.view;
        effect.Projection = cam.projection;
        effect.World = mesh.ParentBone.Transform;
        effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
    }
    mesh.Draw();
}
```

Also sometimes if I rotate the model some weird shadowing appear. Shadows dont even change their "location" but stay drawed exacly the same.

---

**EDIT:** So I googled a bit and saw that enabling MultiSampling should get rid off jagged edges. Now, does anyone know how to do this in WinForms?

**EDIT 2:** About the backbuffer, I am not setting it anywhere so I am guessing it is as it supposed to be.
This is the GraphicsDeviceService.cpp constructor:

```
    GraphicsDeviceService(IntPtr windowHandle, int width, int height)
    {
        parameters = new PresentationParameters();

        parameters.BackBufferWidth = Math.Max(width, 1);
        parameters.BackBufferHeight = Math.Max(height, 1);
        parameters.BackBufferFormat = SurfaceFormat.Color;
        parameters.DepthStencilFormat = DepthFormat.Depth24;
        parameters.DeviceWindowHandle = windowHandle;
        parameters.PresentationInterval = PresentInterval.Immediate;
        parameters.IsFullScreen = false;

        graphicsDevice = new GraphicsDevice(GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter,
                                            GraphicsProfile.Reach,
                                            parameters);
    }
```

Also the reset method sets the backBuffer accordinglly.

**EDIT 3:** 
I tried setting `MultiSampleCount` to bigger number but nothing helped, here are now two picture of what is happening. First I instantiate the object at some place, and then I move camera only right. And the whole object stretches and get these jagged edges, as seen in this picture below. This is the camera movement code:

http://img152.imageshack.us/img152/5204/normalu.png

http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/4434/movedright.png

```
KeyboardState state = Keyboard.GetState();

Vector3 v;

if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) || state.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
    v = new Vector3(0, 0, 1) * moveSpeed;
else if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down) || state.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
    v = new Vector3(0, 0, -1) * moveSpeed;
else if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) || state.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
    v = new Vector3(1, 0, 0) * moveSpeed;
else if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) || state.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
    v = new Vector3(-1, 0, 0) * moveSpeed;
else if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.PageUp))
    v = new Vector3(0, -1, 0) * moveSpeed;
else if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.PageDown))
    v = new Vector3(0, 1, 0) * moveSpeed;
else
    v = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

view *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(v);
```

And the camera view and projection:

```
view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPos, Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);
projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.ToRadians(45f), ratio, 0.5f, 50f);
```

cameraPos is in this case `0,0,10`.

**EDIT: Shadowing**
I  finnaly got a picture of a shadowing problem. As you can see every mesh has its own shadow, instead of just one shadow going thrue all meshes.

http://img843.imageshack.us/img843/8263/weirdshadowing.png

This is the top down view of a model.

Comment: Multisampling will probably help fighting the problem. But I think the root is somewhere else, because the stairs look a bit bigger than usual. Are you sure that the resolution of the back buffer equals the resolution of the control it is rendered to? The odd shading could be a result of some miscalculated normals in the model.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
So how can I enable multisampling?

Comment: Just set `graphics.PreferMultiSampling = true;` But as I said, I doubt that this is the actual solution to your problem. Have you checked the resolutions?

Comment: Have you been able to solve the issue yet?

Answer (score 3):

## Anti-Aliasing for XNA embedded in WinForms

This question is actually a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7425474/925580).

Download the [XNA/WinForms Sample here](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1).

In your `GraphicsDeviceService` class file navigate to the constructor:

```
GraphicsDeviceService(IntPtr windowHandle, int width, int height)
{
    parameters = new PresentationParameters();

    // Add this line
    // Increase the count to get higher quality anti-aliasing
    parameters.MultiSampleCount = 8;

    // More parameter settings and initialization
    // ...
}
```

You can see the difference in the image below:

[image: with and without multisampling comparison]

---

***Old answer***

## Anti-Aliasing for Standard XNA Application

```
graphics.PreferMultiSampling = true;
```

enables anti-aliasing for your backbuffer as explained in this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975403.aspx).

The [`PreferMultiSampling`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphicsdevicemanager.prefermultisampling(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx) property is a member of the [GraphicsDeviceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphicsdevicemanager(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx) class.

### Increase/Decrease Quality

The [`MultiSampleCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.presentationparameters.multisamplecount.aspx) property of the [PresentationParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.presentationparameters.aspx) class can be used to change the number of samples. More samples per pixel means less artifacts and increased render time.

---

## Further Reading on Multisampling

- [Multisampling Anti-Aliasing: A Closeup View](http://alt.3dcenter.org/artikel/multisampling_anti-aliasing/index_e.php)
- [3D Basics 2: Anti-Aliasing, RAM, and Z](http://www.firingsquad.com/guides/3dbasics2/)
- [How It Works: Fragment Anti-Aliasing](http://www.firingsquad.com/guides/fragmentaa/default.asp)

---

Please note that this solution will only be effective if the source of the problem lies within the graphics pipeline, more specifically the rasterizer.

As noted by [Nico Schertler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431477/jagged-edges-and-weird-shadowing#comment18378043_13431477), make sure that the image resolution is not changed in the process of embedding it into WinForms. If the steps on the edges are not exactly one pixel wide it is a strong indicator that the problem comes from the presentation of the texture in WinForms.

I cannot address the shadow problem here, as it is hard to guess the light settings from the images.

Comment: There is no such thing as **GraphicsDevice.PreferMutliSampling** there is just **GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState.MultiSampleAntiAlias** which I cannot set to true, but says it already is defaultly set to true.
So, seems you were right, the mutlisampling isnt a problem. When I check for the width and height property of **GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode** it doesnt match the width and height of the control. But the **GraphicsDevice.Viewport** width and height matches the controls size. So which one is not correct?

Comment: The `PreferMultiSampling` property is a member of the `GraphicsDeviceManager` class and **not** of the `GraphicsDevice` class. Per default there should be a field called `graphics` in your game class. Please make sure to read the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975403.aspx) I already linked to in the answer and try to follow the steps.
For the width and height: it's the backbuffer size that is relevant. Check the `graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth` and `graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight`.

Comment: There is no Game class in WinForms :/

Comment: I didn't check out the sample at first. My answer now includes the instructions for the WinForms sample.

Comment: I have also tried downloading that sample and setting the **MultiSampleCount** in there but nothing changed. Did you do any other changed to that sample project? Or maybe my graphics card just doesnt support this?

Comment: I redownloaded the sample as well. Setting the `MultiSampleCount` was the only thing needed to make it work on my device. It could have to do with your graphics card, but I am really no expert on that. At least we seem to have narrowed down the problem. Good luck!